Is it possible to define 'not(p)' in a deflationary theory of truth?
This question is a follow-up question to another recent question about deflationary theories of truth.
According to one comment:

The point of the deflationary account of truth is that there is nothing that truth is really like. Truth isn't a thing. It isn't a property. To say that it's true that it's raining is just to say that it's raining. There is nothing extra there. "True" isn't a property that you are attributing to the proposition "It's raining"; "true" is just a word that makes it easier to emphasize a certain aspect of the proposition.

So, if I understand this correctly, then, according to a deflationary account of truth,

(by definition) 'p is true' iff 'p'

or, equivalently

the assertion 'p is true' means the same as the assertion 'p'.

In other words,

the meaning of an assertion that some assertion p is true is fully captured by or fully equivalent to simply making that assertion p.

('Fully captured' and 'equivalent to' here of course (?) need to be taken to mean something like: assuming we're only/mostly interested in language used to try to state or establish facts. We're only/mostly interested in the semantic aspects of those speech acts and in the logical aspects of language usage; we're ignoring any pragmatic aspects such as establishing focus or topic, implicit clarification of context, or emotive aspects, and the like.)
My question then is: Doesn't this theory of truth run into problems with logical connectives? How are logical connectives and operators defined under this theory? In particular, how can the logical 'not' be defined? It seems to me that in any assertion 'not p' the term p is always used as indexical term (a proper name as it were, referring to an imagined, possible fact) so it doesn't seem possible to define the meaning of 'not p' in terms of any other proposition that does not use 'not' and/or does not somehow either use 'is true' as predicate or some proxy/alternative for 'is true'.
You could claim that (under deflationarism) 'not' can be simply defined in the usual truth-functional way. Put up a truth-table; the truth table is taken as the meaning. But in this case, under a deflationary theory, this seems to amount to a circular definition:

(by definition) "not(p) is true" iff "p is not true"

Or not? Am I missing something?
The only way out, it seems, is to use some other predicate (something like 'p doesn't hold' or 'p does not obtain') but that seems to conflict (or be incoherent) with (or at least change) the original definition of 'is true' (for propositions without logical operators).
Is this seen as a problem in deflationary accounts? If so, what kind of solutions are provided? If not, then what am I missing?

Update: I'm not sure if 'not' is special. For any of the logical connectives I actually have the same question; it's just that for 'not' the problem somehow seems extra acute. Perhaps because of some assumptions I'm making (assumptions which I have trouble unearthing).

To a deflationist, "not-P is true" is equivalent to not-P. Likewise for other connectives. So I'm not sure why you think negation is a problem specifically for the deflationary theory of truth. If anything, the correspondence theory has more trouble with negation, since we might ask what state of affairs not-P corresponds to. Some philosophers consider it problematic to speak of negative facts or negative states of affairs. If you are asking about the semantics of negation, there are many theories of that. Entire books have been written about it. It might help to clarify the question.

Ok, thanks. So a deflationarist also just uses the truth-value tables to define the connectives? I cannot quite put my finger on why I find that strange/unsatisfactory - cannot really express it better than in the question. (But I did also have in mind that no(p) cannot refer to any state of affairs.)

@nwr - Tarski's theory is not a deflationary theory (DT). In Tarski's theory truth is a substantive (non-redundant) concept, an extra, new property that sentences can have. In a DT truth is redundant; 'is true' is merely a linguistic convenience - which implies that 'is true' can always be totally removed from the language without loss (in expressibility). Perhaps my problem is just that I tend to think of 'is truth' as very close to 'is provable', 'is valid' (and similar) - so DT doesn't make much sense to me.

Perhaps a deflated 'true' ('authentic' may be the more appropriate word for deflationists such as Heidegger) wisdom starts from seeing those which are being and those which are being-not instead of the usual not-being with the negation logical connective as Heidegger used to say 'let being be and thus implicitly 'let being-not be-not not not-being'...

Deflationists may define negation and the other connectives in the usual way. With classical logic this is straightforward: you can use T-schemas or truth tables. For other logics, setting out the semantics requires more work. There are many objections to deflationism. I'm inclined to agree that saying "...is true" is not redundant. It is like saying "...is actually the case". It states of a proposition that it holds in the actual world. In some varieties of modal logic, there is an 'actually' operator that is not redundant.

@Bumble certainly adding actual operator or other usual modal operators are helpful for the sake of modal logics, but truth still could be deflated in the same way as to seeing a not-dog is meant to seeing a cat or any other dog-not's which is actually a good thing for people to better intuit intuitionistic logics whose meta-entailment is pure provability which has no direct correspondent relation with the usual supposed property of truth assuming it really exists...

@DoubleKnot If I understand you correctly, then I agree. From a realist perspective, "P is true" deflates to P, while to an intuitionist, "P is provable" deflates to P. To a neutral observer, this is a substantive disagreement and it means that, "is true" and "is provable" are properties of P. When the realist says "P is true" they should be understood as committing to realism about P. In practice, the use of "is true" in natural language is much more unruly and difficult to pin down.

@Bumble René Descartes once doubted everything except his cogito so he must also doubted the 'unruly' appearance of 'is true' in Latin/French natural languages. Other deflationists such as Heidegger wouldn't have any disadvantage for those present-at-hand, but as you rightly commented would face technical limitations of emergent expression power for those ready-to-hand. But I doubt whether there really exists a neutral unbiased observer besides the obvious nihilists and if I have to pick I'd rather say deflational realists are more neutral though they cannot convert intuitionists decisively...
